# Android Studio - How to monitor device after reboot?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat, android-log

I'm developing an app with a BootReceiver class which is misbehaving so I would like to view its `Log.d(...)` output after the device is restarted.

When the app restarts, it shows as DEAD in the Android Monitor tab so no log output is shown. Is there any way I can view the log output (pref. via Android Studio)?

(Could find nothing on Google or on the official [Debugging with Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html) page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can select: "No Filters".

This way, whole log will be displayed.

Then, you can filter the log by your log tag (or any other text that you are search for).

[image]

Comment: Great stuff - works a treat, thanks! Will accept your answer in a mo. :-)